# LinkedIn callback not working for certain URLs (using Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, linkedin-api

LinkedIn doesn't seem to like the idea of redirecting back to my test site.

This code directs me to the LinkedIn confirm page without any problems:
(This is pretty much a boilerplate example using Zend's OAuth)

```
$options = array(
    'version'               => '1.0',
    'callbackUrl'           => 'http://dev.local/',
    'requestTokenUrl'       => 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken',
    'userAuthorizationUrl'  => 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize',
    'accessTokenUrl'        => 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken',
    'consumerKey'           => [api],
    'consumerSecret'        => [secret]
);

$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer( $options );

// Start Requesting a LinkedIn Request Token
$token = $consumer->getRequestToken ();

// Store the LinkedIn Request Token
$_SESSION ['REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize ( $token );

// Redirect the Web User to LinkedIn Authentication  Page
$consumer->redirect ();
```

However if my callback is `http://dev.local/` it does not redirect, but if I specify a valid domain (like `http://www.google.com`) it redirects with no problem.

This behaviour happened recently (it was working fine until about a month ago). This is obviously a serious pain since I need to deploy code to be able to test anything.

Is this a problem people have experienced and has anyone found a way to get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems this is because [LinkedIn changed their API](http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/making-it-easier-you-develop-linkedin), specifically how the api interacts with Oauth:

> On the technical side, we've borrowed the OAuth 2.0 concept of the
> "scope" parameter and incorporated it into our OAuth 1.0a and JS
> Authentication flows.

Seems other apps, plugins and libraries are experiencing some difficulty with this as well.

Comment: Any feedback from LinkedIn on this problem?